# Medical image dataset

Tags: image-processing

I am doing some project on medical image processing and I need some uncompressed medical images especially magnetic resonance angiography, vessel and so on. I have searched a lot but most of the available images are in JPEG format which is not a suitable format due to its lossy compression. Do you know any free dataset which have uncompressed medical images especially those mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are most likely having is that you need to search for files in the correct format.  DICOM is what you need to look for.
A few hits:

1. [One example](http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/images/)
2. [A library from a DICOM viewer software producer](http://www.osirix-viewer.com/datasets/)
3. [A library of images from Siemens](http://www.healthcare.siemens.com/magnetic-resonance-imaging/magnetom-world/clinical-corner/protocols/dicom-images)

You will also need a DICOM viewer.
[Image J](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/download.html)  is free (non-commercial, no restrictions on use) and can be used under Windows, Mac, and Linux - it does require Java.
There are other viewers available, free as well as commercial.  Just search for DICOM viewers.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand this question better, please see the question [What are characteristics of different MR images?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27994/what-are-characteristics-of-different-mr-images).

## **Summary about MR images in medicine**

1. [Standford volume data archieve](https://graphics.stanford.edu/data/voldata/)
2. [Physionet](http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/images/)
3. [DICOM](http://www.healthcare.siemens.com/magnetic-resonance-imaging/magnetom-world/clinical-corner/protocols/dicom-images)

and [Data analytics in life sciences](http://www.dataanalyticslifesciences.com/) discusses the usage of bigdata in medicine and profiting from it (restricted access).

## **More on Medical data: Bigdata, Personal data, ...**

Similar questions, perhaps similar goals

1. [Why is machine learning not more widely used for medical diagnosis](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-machine-learning-not-more-widely-used-for-medical-diagnosis?)
2. [Where do medical researchers get their data from?](https://www.quora.com/Where-do-medical-researchers-get-their-data-from) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Like-PhysioNet-is-there-any-other-website-which-provides-other-medical-data-like-CT-MRI-and-ultrasound)
3. [Medical voxel data?](https://www.quora.com/Where-is-medical-voxel-data-available-for-research)
4. [Data.Medicare.gov](http://data.medicare.gov) on nursing data, physician data, ...

Other medical data, general, perhaps relevant

1. [Image analysis on brain](http://segem.brain.mpg.de/) such as neuron detection
2. [RCSB](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do) about structural view on proteins and [BioBlender](http://www.bioblender.eu/) on its visualisation
3. [Physiological signals](http://physionet.org/) and [here](http://physionet.org/physiobank/)

## More curiosity, data, future research

- There may be some medical dataset used for salient object segmentation  [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27992/image-datasets-used-for-salient-objects).
- Quora has a label on [Medical Information and Data](https://www.quora.com/topic/Medical-Information-and-Data) but it is relatively hard to find MR images by it.
- [Large datasets open to public?](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public)

Answer (score 0):

You have another famous and important source of information, the so well known [DICOM Library](https://www.dicomlibrary.com/). Intending for anonymization, the [DICOM Library](https://www.dicomlibrary.com/) is sharing and viewing of [DICOM Standard](https://www.dicomstandard.org/) online.

For instance, if you want a parser to it you have the [DICOM Parser in Go](https://github.com/gillesdemey/go-dicom) repository. It is a DICOM Parser developed in the [Go Programming Language](https://golang.org/).