# Image datasets used for salient objects?

Tags: data-request

I would like to understand reasons for different image datasets used for salient object detection: their difficulties, their origins and likely future datasets. Does there exist any work explaining them such their progression and characteristics over time?

Answer (score 1):

**Datasets explicitly mentioning saliency**

1. [MSRA](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/jiansun/SalientObject/salient_object.htm)
2. [SOD](http://elderlab.yorku.ca/SOD/) based on [BSD Berkeley segmentation dataset](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html)

**Apparently more general datasets (not researched in detail)**

3. [DUT-Omron Image dataset](http://202.118.75.4/lu/DUT-OMRON/index.htm)
4. THUS
5. ECSD
6. PASCAL
7. ...

**More challenging situations with more noise**

- Detection on magnetism such as MR: [Medical image dataset](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19463/medical-image-dataset) and [Extract voice from magnetic tape](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25125/extract-voice-from-magnetic-tape/25586#25586)